# null values in sql

Tags: sql, null

i have data like this

```
ID Nu     name 
1  234    asd
2  566    asd
3  -      sdf
4  356    sd
5  NULL   sfsg
```

now how to get all data with - and null values

Comment: `where nu is null or nu = '-'`

Comment: `NULL` is *not* a value - it's the **absence** of a value ....

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table_name;
```

this will give you all the data with - and null value

if you want to fetch only the data where nu is null and `-` use this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where nu is null or nu = '-';
```

I think this should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where Nu is null or Nu='-'
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all the info from the table you can use the following query:

```
select * from table_name;
```

To filter by null and dash values, try the where clause:

```
select * from table_name where nu is null;
UNION ALL
select * from table_name where nu = '-';
```